# Android API 7 (2.1), MapView, MultiThreading, ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: android, multithreading, android-mapview

First of all, i don't know where, i don't know why, i get ConcurrentModificationException. My Logcat is out of order (or just i can't use it) but never shows any information about exceptions ( i read lots of article about it, and nothing helped, maybe can't debug my phone correctly )

Secondly sorry about my confused english, i try to formulate as clearly as i can, codes could help, please help me

**So, The problem is the next:**

i use Mapview and 5 custom CustomItemizedOverlay (Source no. 1) on it.
From MapView i start some (1, 2, max 5) threads to webservice (Source no. 2) and after i get results back (it's List) i draw them into mapoverlay (source no. 3)

so MapView ( implements 5 ResponseHandlerInterfaces ) sends requests to webservice through myActions (extends Thread) and when actions gets responses, they call responseHandler.reportResponseList(List list) methods. (MapView get back the control right here)

```java
and all of it causes ConcurrentModificationException sometimes
(rarely ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)
```

i have got Options Activity to set required lists and i also have got Refresh button, to get lists. let me lead you through one example.

I just opened MapView, it's empty. I need only 1 kind of objects. I tap refresh, after network communication, i get markers on my mapview. cool, it's working. Now i'm going to Options, and i set more objects to request. Use Refresh again at mapview, and sometimes i get all kinds of objects, sometimes i get ConcurrentModificationException.

Source No. 1

```
public class CustomItemizedOverlay<T> extends ItemizedOverlay<T>{

private Context mContext;
private Object lock = new Object();
private CopyOnWriteArrayList<T> overlays = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<T>();

public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable marker, Context context) {
    super(boundCenterBottom(marker));
    this.mContext = context;
    populate();
}
@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index){
 // doesn't matter
}
public void clear(){
    synchronized (lock) {
        overlays.clear();
    }
}
public void addOverlay(T overlay){
    synchronized (lock) {
        overlays.add(overlay);
        setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
        populate();
    }
}
public void removeOverlay(int selected){
    synchronized (lock) {
        overlays.remove(selected);
        populate();
        setLastFocusedIndex(-1);
    }
}
@Override
protected T createItem(int i) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        return overlays.get(i);         
    }
}
@Override
public int size() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        return overlays.size();
    }
}
public void setLock(Object o){
        this.lock = o;
    }
}
```

Source No. 2

MapView:

```
public class MyMap extends MapActivity implements LocationListener, RestResPonseHandler { // there are 5 type of responsehandlers, one for each overlay 

private MapView mapView;
private MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay;

private Object lock = new Object();

private CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem<MyObject1>> my1Overlay;
private CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem<MyObject2>> my2Overlay;
private CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem<MyObject3>> my3Overlay;
private CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem<MyObject4>> my4Overlay;
private CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem<MyObject5>> my5Overlay;

public void getObject1List(){ // there are 5 getList methods
    new RestAction(this).start(); // 'this' is the object which implements required RestResponseHandler interface. in every case it will be 'this'. MyMap implements all kind of required RestResponseHandler interfaces
    }
```

Source No. 3 (non main thread) // This is pattern for each 'CustomItemizedOverlay filling method'. After actions reports results (list of objects), mapview fills actual overlay with OverlayItems

```
@Override
public void reportResponseList(List<MyObject1> objects) {
    if (my1Overlay == null){
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable marker = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
        my1Overlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem<MyObject1>>(marker, this);
        my1Overlay.setLock(lock); // MyMap has lock object, look at source 2 (also CustomItemizedOverlay (source 1) )
        mapOverlays.add(my1Overlay);
    } else {
        my1Overlay.clear(); 
    }   
    synchronized (lock) {
        for(int i=0;i<objects.size();++i){
            MyObject1 object = objects.get(i);
            CustomOverlayItem<MyObject1> item = new CustomOverlayItem<CustomBuilding>(object.getPositionId(), object);
            my1Overlay.addOverlay(item);
        }
    refreshView();
    }
}
```

Where refreshView posts runnable to main thread to update mapView.

```
public void refreshView(){
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            mapView.post(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    mapView.invalidate();
                }
            }); 
        }
    }).start();
}
```

**The Solution**: 
After CommonsWare's answer, i modified my source to :

```
@Override
public void reportResponseList(final List<MyObject1> objects) {     
    if (my1Overlay == null){
        List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        Drawable marker = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
        my1Overlay = new CustomItemizedOverlay<CustomOverlayItem<MyObject1>>(marker, this);
        my1Overlay.setLock(lock);
        mapOverlays.add(my1Overlay);
    } else {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                my1Overlay.clear();
            }
        }); 
    }
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            for(int i=0;i<objects.size();++i){
                MyObject1 object = objects.get(i);
                CustomOverlayItem<MyObject1> item = new CustomOverlayItem<MyObject1>(object.getPositionId(), object);
                my1Overlay.addOverlay(item);
            }
            refreshView();  
        }
    });
}
```

and now at this moment it seems to work. i don't know how pretty is it, but seems to work. (maybe mapOverlays.add() method should be on main thread too) Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `my1Overlay` is already part of the `MapView` by the time `reportResponseList()` is called, you should not be modifying it on a background thread. `MapView` will be using that `Overlay`. Instead, create a new `Overlay` in the background thread, the swap overlays (remove the old, add the new) on the main application thread.

Comment: so Should my1Overlay.clear() and synchronized loop have to run on main thread?

Comment: @Victor: That is another possibility, though you should no longer need it to be `synchronized`, if everyone accessing it is doing so on the main application thread.

Comment: and Could mapOverlays.add(my1Overlay); be on non-main thread?

Comment: @Victor: I do not recommend that.

Comment: okay, now i can't cause the exceptions, it seems to work. i will accept your answer in a minute

Comment: i tried to swap overlays too, but in that case, doesn't appear any marker on map (that way i tried) so it isn't work for me, thanks again. (i updated this issue with new source)